# Minecraft LAN Nether crashing the game

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I can't seem to find an answer ANYWHERE. DH and I are trying to enter the Nether. I can enter the Nether just fine on my own. I'm using the "open to LAN" option, but I spent 2 hours configuring a minecraft server and that got me nowhere closer to the answer. Once LAN is up, we can't enter. Has it always been this way?

Two Questions:

1. Can the Nether and the End be accessed on a LAN party game?
2. How do I upload our (currently singleplayer) world to the new minecraft server I spent forever just getting to open?

This is on minecraft version 1.10.2, windows 10, as of Jul '16

Comment: Answer to question #2, it completely depends on the server hoster, Plugins, mods, versions. You might be able to save your world as a schematic and implement it using MCEdit.

Comment: Uploading the world folder should work fine if the server version matches (and the provider allows it). You need to upload world_nether and world_the_end as well, if you want to use yours. Otherwise they'll get freshly generated. About the crashes you should maybe provide us with some details (crash log file or stacktrace). It seems the map upload/sync to the client gets blocked somehow.

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes the Nether and the End can be accessed on a LAN party game.
2. To upload world file:

First open Minecraft as you know.

[image]

Note somehwhere that sub-name of your world.

Then open Minecraft's data directory.

If you don't know how to do this, this screenshot will help you.
[image]

Find the folder named `saves`.

Find the world you noted, and copy it to server directory.

After that rename it to `world`.

Make sure in `server.properties`, `allow-nether` equals `true`.